# Finding the coefficients that equate two sides of an equation

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials, coefficients

I have the following equation : $f(x)p(x)=g(x)p(\frac{x}{q}) + g(\frac{1}{xq})p(xq)$

q is a constant and $f(x)$ is a polynomial whose expression I have. Similarly $g(x)$ is also a known function.

$p(x)$ is a Laurent polynomial of the following form : $\sum\limits _{k=0} ^M b_k (x^{2k}+(x q)^{-2k})$

What I want to do is find a way to compute the coefficients $b_k$ of the polynomial $p(x)$ that allow us to have the equality just like in the equation I wrote in the beginning.

This is an example of the equality I got out of my code :

For the left hand side I got :

```
4.82866 b0 - 3.51211 b1 + (0.0258044 b1)/x^8 + (0.0940375 b0)/x^6 + (0.369225 b1)/x^6 + (1.34554 b0)/x^4 - (0.916725 b1)/x^4-3.51211 b0)/x^2 + (1.99778 b1)/x^2 - 6.39949 b0 x^2 + 3.6402b1 x^2 + 4.46736 b0 x^4 -3.04363 b1 x^4 + 0.568894 b0 x^6 + 2.23368 b1 x^6 + 0.284447 b1 x^8
```

For the right hand side I got:

```
1/(x^8 (0.301194 - 1.09762 x^4 + 
1. x^8)) (b0 x^2 (-0.036292 - 0.424965 x^2 + 1.28982 x^4 - 
  0.0798095 x^6 - 2.2297 x^8 + 3.11271 x^10 - 4.06278 x^12 - 
  0.264977 x^14 + 7.80293 x^16 - 4.68447 x^18 - 0.728943 x^20) + 
b1 (-0.00840069 - 0.0395742 x^2 + 0.143327 x^4 - 0.707572 x^6 + 
  1.50711 x^8 + 1.42067 x^10 - 6.34233 x^12 + 2.58863 x^14 + 
  5.00377 x^16 - 4.28056 x^18 + 1.57991 x^20 - 0.79487 x^22 - 
  0.30745 x^24))
```

Is there a straightforward way to get (in case they exist) the coefficients $b_k$ that allow for the left hand side to be equal the right hand side ?

Comment: In principle, this is a job for `SolveAlways` but here it just returns that the two b's should be 0

Comment: Clearly there is a solution with all the `b`s zero.  So perhaps you need to look for a solution with `b[0]==1` (for example)

Comment: There's no solution. The denominators don't match. Probably because the rational functions were computed with inexact floating-point numbers, leading to round off errors and lack of cancellation.

Comment: @lukaslang that was a problem I was also facing so maybe i'll use the advice of mikado. Thanks for the SolveAlways I will try to use it.

Comment: @mikado I will try also with b[0]==1 as you mentioned, thanks for the advice ! But I don't know how to find the other coefficients, maybe I should use SolveAlways, just like Lukas Lang suggested ?

Comment: @michaelE2 You're right about the round off errors I will try to fix those as well in my code. However, I chose a random (with the simplest and smallest polynomial) example just to give an idea about what I am trying to solve . I will also try to solve other equations (with bigger polynomials and different constants q) where I might actually get non-zero solutions and that's why I want to know if there's a straightforward way to do so.

Comment: `SolveAlways` is designed for this, but it requires that the two sides have coefficients that match up. However, if you are working with approximate data, then numerical approaches are probably called for. One usually minimizes the norm of a difference or residual, instead of trying to solve exactly.

Comment: @michaele2 okay ! thanks a lot I will try modifying my code to get exact numerical results and if it won't work I will try numerical approaches.